# Retrieve data from active directory

Tags: java, active-directory

I am developing a project in java and JSP that needs to access an active directory for login and retrieving some values. I have done the login part(authentication) but i am not able to get help over the retrieval part.I am completely new to active directory concept, so please aid me accordingly.
I am giving the code of the java class that i have used for user authentication:

```
 package classes;

    import java.util.Hashtable;
    import javax.naming.Context;
    import javax.naming.NamingException;
    import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
    import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;

    public class AD_Auth {

    private static final String CONTEXT_FACTORY_CLASS ="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";
    private static final String domainName = "@xyz.IN";
    private static final String providerUrl = "ldap://srdeladc02.xyz.in:123";

    public static boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {

        try {
            Hashtable<Object, Object> env = new Hashtable<Object, Object>();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, CONTEXT_FACTORY_CLASS);
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerUrl);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username + domainName);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
                        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "strong");
            DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
            ctx.close();

            return true;

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println("Dear User, The username or password you have entered is in correct, please try again.");
        }

        return false;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // if someone emailid is myemail#icar.gov.in then username will be myemail
        //System.out.println(AD_Auth.authenticate("username", "password"));

    }

}
```